# WPF - Xceed GridControl - saving when edited row has focus

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid

I have an XCeed grid with cell editing enabled.
When i make a change to my cell, leave the row and then save it is persited to the database.

But when i hit my save button when the changed cell is still selected the change doens't get persisted.

How can i make sure when i save the current content is saved?

My Grid xaml:

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MySource}}"
                          BorderThickness="1" AutoCreateColumns="False" ReadOnly="False" NavigationBehavior="CellOnly">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.DefaultCellEditors>
            <xcdg:CellEditor x:Key="{x:Type system:Boolean}">
                <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <xcdg:CheckBox xcdg:Cell.IsCellFocusScope="True"
                                       IsChecked="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"
                                       HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                       />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>

                <xcdg:CellEditor.ActivationGestures>
                    <xcdg:TextInputActivationGesture />
                </xcdg:CellEditor.ActivationGestures>

            </xcdg:CellEditor>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.DefaultCellEditors>

        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Description" FieldName="Description" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Start period" FieldName="Start" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <xcdg:Column Title="End Period" FieldName="End" ReadOnly="True"/>
            <xcdg:Column Title="Finished" FieldName="IsFinished"/>                
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <!--<xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>-->

    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted my question, please state why so i can improve.